# Google Geocoding API - "va" returns "vatican" instead of "virginia"

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google's Geocoding API to take a natural language input and convert it to lat/long coordinates.

My requests look like so:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=va&region=US

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=birmingham&region=US

However, in both instances I am receiving results in Europe.  How can I bias the results to a country?  Is my only option to explicitly specify the bounds of each country per request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "US" to the end of the address parameter. I.e. this works:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=va%2C%20US&region=US

Comment: This works perfectly and saved quite a bit of time.  For anyone else reading this, I'm using a CMS which is language aware.  I'm basically taking the region code from the context langauge (e.g., en-GB or en-US) and appending the country code to the query.  Works like a charm.